# Python yield inside lambda function

Tags: python, generator, pytest, pymongo

I am trying to create a `pytest` fixture that takes an argument and yields a `pymongo.MongoClient`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def mongo_test_db(django_db_setup) -> Database:
    """ Fixture to use in tests that require access to Mongo

    Drops database first to ensure a clean state.

    Depends on the external Mongo process running in the background


    Changes setting MONGO_CONNECTION to MONGO_TEST_CONNECTION defined in settings.
    """
    def _generate(db_name):
        assert settings.MONGO_TEST_CONNECTION, "MONGO_TEST_CONNECTION not defined"

        settings.MONGO_CONNECTION = settings.MONGO_TEST_CONNECTION

        client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_CONNECTION)
        client[db_name].command("dropDatabase")
        yield client[db_name]
        client[db_name].command("dropDatabase")

    return _generate
```

The code does work, but instead of yielding and actual value of generator I get a generator object instead; therefore, I need to call `next(mongo_test_db("test"))` instead of `mongo_test_db("test")`

I want to simply call mongo_test_db("test") and get the actual pymongo client, not the generator object.

Comment: That's _the_ thing about `generators`; they evaluate lazily. And where is the `lambda` function, I can't see?

Comment: No sure what do you really want to achieve if you could elaborate on what is your goal maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Then you need to use `return client[db_name]`, not `yield client[db_name]`, because it sounds like you don't *want* a `generator`. That said, why are you executing `dropDatabase` twice, once before and once after the `yield`? The function you are defining looks vaguely like a context manager you would create with `contextlib.contextmanager`.

Comment: I guess I used a wrong terminology for returning a function object instead of a function call. But isn't that what lambdas are (except for the scope of parameters)? @mustafa-aydin

Comment: Its unclear to me why you must define the nested generate function. Why cant you put the db setup directly in the fixture function?

Comment: @chepner I want to yield it, to drop all data after the yield call. I am not sure about using `contextmanager` as pytest fixture, are you familiar with that?

Comment: @Wombatz that's the nature of `pytest.fixtures` and I want to be able to parametrize the fixture, this is a way for achieving that.

Comment: @YevgenPonomarenko no, lambdas are merely anonymous functions that should be exclusively used as throw-aways in parameters that expect functions. You are returning a genuine function object.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea to add parameters to a fixture function. But maybe you dont need a fixture at all, a simple contextmanager like chepner suggested sounds perfect here.

Comment: @MustafaAydın There's just the one kind of `function`; they are created by either lambda expressions or `def` statements. Lambda expressions are *limited* in which `function` objects they can create, due to the fact that they are single expressions, not an arbitrary sequence of statements.